# How to BInd RDLC with stored procedure dynamically with out changes in report itself

Tags: stored-procedures, dynamic, dataset, rdlc

I am binding RDLC (Report viewer) with a stored procedure. There is a problem that if the number of columns changes in the stored procedure then the report viewer must be updated automatically without any change in the report design or datasets.

Otherwise each time the number of columns changes, the whole report has to be changed.

Comment: You need to provide more details about the data, because in some cases it can be done dynamically (when matrix report is called to the rescue) and sometimes it is not possible.

Comment: I saw one video on matrix report but it was looking complex. My motive is just to not compile the whole code. Just need to change the script of SP only.

Comment: It's not really complex. All it is - adding grouping for columns in addition (or instead of) row grouping. But again, need to show your data and explain the reason for dynamic column number requirement.